# Как с помощью jsoup найти элемент в дереве?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти такие элементы?

```
<div  id="tennis3012766Item" class="subitem">
......
</div>

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

// находит элементы где class = "subitem"
Elements els = doc.select("div.subitem");

// находит элементы с id типа tennis24566
// Element els = doc.select("id=~tennis");
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) все написано.
Найти элемент по id (один элемент. id уникален для всего документа):

```
Element content = doc.getElementById("tennis3012766Item");
```

Найти все элементы по любому атрибуту (в том числе и id):

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("id", "tennis");
```

Найти все элементы по классу:

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("subitem");
```